# python call function inside for loop and function contain if else structure

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I have the following python code that call a function that iterate over a dict.
the code below not work as expected:

```
list1=["test1","test2","test3","test4"]
list2=["toto1","test1","test3","toto4"]

def functest(t):
    for l in list2:
        if t == l:
            return cond1
        else:
            return "rien"

for t in list1:
    titi=functest(t)
    print titi
```

When I print titi var I have toto1 printed 4 times.

If I remove the else inside my function the code seem to work.

How you can explain this behavior ?

Why when I add else with a returned string only the string is printed.

thanks

Comment: what is `cond1`??? You need to provide code that users can runs as-is that reproduces the error. This code will produce a `NamerError` if the `if` condition is ever `True`, so clearly you are leaving something out

Comment: Please provide a proper example (see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This code, however, just prints `"rien"` len(list1) times, because you `return` *inside* your loop, and `"toto1"` always fails `if t == l`, so you always go to the `else` block which returns after the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Because `return` exits the function and returns your program back to the loop. So when you add the `else` statement within the loop, the current element of `list1` is compared against `'toto1'`, enters the `else` statement, and the function returns `"rien"`.

```
def functest(t):
    for l in list2:
        if t == l: 
            return cond1
        else:
            return "rien" # we always end up here on the first iteration, 
                          # when comparing against "toto1"
```

When you *remove* the `else` statement, you loop *until* you find a match in `list2`. However, assuming you still want to return `"rien"` given that none of the elements in `list2` match the element in `list1` which is being checked, you should move the return statement out of the loop, so that it is only returned after checking all elements.

```
def functest(t):
    for l in list2:
        if t == l:
            return "match found"
    return "rien"
```

**Demo**

```
>>> for t in list1:
       titi=functest(t)
       print (titi)

match found
rien
match found
rien
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to modify code in order to implement your logic.

```
list1=["test1","test2","test3","test4"]
list2=["toto1","test1","test3","toto4"]

def functest(t):
  newReturnList=[]
  for l in list2:
     if t == l:
        newReturnList.append(t+'-found') 
     else:
        newReturnList.append(t+'-NOT found')

return newReturnList


for t in list1:
    titi=functest(t)
   print (titi)
```

Comment: HI Naqi Abedi. Adding an explanation of how this code is different, and how it solves the problem would make this a better answer.